# Cleaning and simplifying function that returns a number based on certain values

Tags: python, mathematics

I have a rather clunky function that returns a number based on certain values:

```
local = {'abs154': '4'}

w12,sv2,sv4,sv6,sv8,sv10,sv12=75,95,110,104,101,110,116 
supers = [["5", w12], ["6", w12], ["7", w12], ["8", w12], ["16", w12], ["17", w12], ["18", w12], ["9", sv2], ["11", sv2], ["12", sv2], ["13", sv2], ["14", sv2], ["15", sv2], ["19", sv4], ["23", sv4], ["24", sv4], ["25", sv4], ["26", sv4], ["28", sv6], ["29", sv6], ["30", sv6], ["31", sv6], ["32", sv6], ["33", sv6], ["35", sv8], ["36", sv8], ["37", sv8], ["38", sv8], ["39", sv8], ["40", sv8], ["41", sv8], ["42", sv8], ["43", sv8], ["44", sv8], ["45", sv8], ["46", sv8], ["47", sv8], ["48", sv8], ["49", sv8], ["50", sv8], ["52", sv10], ["53", sv10], ["55", sv10], ["57", sv10], ["58", sv10], ["59", sv10], ["60", sv10], ["61", sv10], ["62", sv10], ["63", sv10], ["64", sv10], ["65", sv10], ["66", sv10], ["68", sv2], ["71", sv12], ["72", sv12], ["73", sv12], ["74", sv12], ["75", sv12], ["76", sv12], ["77", sv12], ["78", sv12], ["79", sv12], ["80", sv12], ["81", sv12], ["82", sv12], ["83", sv12], ["84", sv12]] 

def Server(group): 
      try: sn = local[group] 
      except KeyError: 
            group = group.replace("-", "q") 
            fnv = float(int(group[0:min(5, len(group))], 36)) 
            lnv = group[6: (6 + min(3, len(group) - 5))] 
            if(lnv): 
                lnv = float(int(lnv, 36)) 
                lnv = max(lnv,1000) 
            else: 
                lnv = 1000 
            num = (fnv % lnv) / lnv 
            maxnum = sum(map(lambda x: x[1], supers)) 
            cumfreq = 0 
            sn = 0 
            for wgt in supers: 
                cumfreq += float(wgt[1]) / maxnum 
                if(num <= cumfreq): 
                    sn = int(wgt[0]) 
                    break 
      return "s" + str(sn) + ".website.com"
```

This all looks rather unnecessary.  I would like to make it shorter and cleaner if possible.

Comment: sorry about the lack of code blocks. seems a bit different than stack

Comment: Just click the code brackets in the editor toolbar while having the code selected

Comment: edited. was referred here by stack, yet no luck thus far

Comment: @user2602977 Have you considered breaking this down into subfunctions with suggestive names?

Comment: What is the motivation for this code?  I suspect that it's excessively complicated because of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

Answer (score 2):

some style issues to consider:

1) it's conventional to use ALL_CAPS for constants such as 'supers' and w1, etc.

2) for long term maintenance, it's also a good idea to use longer more descriptive names - not only is this hard to parse for the uninitiated, it's also prone to hard-to-catch typos which will be hard to spot.  It's especially bad when you do multiple assignments on a single line.

3) supers could be a dictionary

4) you can simplify the range logic by excepting for incomplete groups:

```
<snip>
enter code here
group = group.replace("-", "q") 
fnv, lnv = None
try:    
   fnv = group[:5] 
   lnv = group[6:9]
except IndexError:
   raise ValueError "group string %s is malformed"
fn_value = int(fnv, 36)
ln_value = max(int(lnv, 36), 1000) or 1000
```

5) maxNum is always the same, it should be a constant or a cached module-level field:

```
informative_name = sum(map(lambda x: x[1], supers))
```

at the top will execute at module load and wont need to be recalced for every call.

Answer (score 0):

- Extract two functions from the except clause: one that extracts `num` from `group`, and one that looks up `sn` from `super`
- Precomputing `cumfreq` into `super` would allow easy lookup with help from the `bisect` module.
- `group[0:min(5, len(group))]` is same as `group[:5]` and `group[6: (6 + min(3, len(group) - 5))]` same as `group[6:9]`
- There are redundant type conversions: `lnv` is made `float` but possibly replaced by the integer `1000`, and `sn` goes from `str` to `int` to `str`.